# Erreur lors de la configuration de la classe d'écoute de l'application (application listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListner

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I am having a problem with spring , i am a newbie using this framework with Hibernate , JPA and Maven , I am following a tutorial on pluralsight but when launching the app in the server i have this error message

```
Grave: Erreur lors de la configuration de la classe d'écoute de l'application (application listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListner
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListner
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4876)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

   févr. 11, 2014 10:49:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
```

this is my "**web.xml**"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <context-param>

    <param-name>contextConfigLocation </param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/jpaContext.xml</param-value>

    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListner</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml, /WEB-INF/config/jpaContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/pdfs/**</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/images/**</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

and this is my "**jpacontext.xml**"

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect" />
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

            </map>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" >
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
        <property name ="driverClassName" value="com.postgresql.jdbc.driver" />
        <property name ="url" value="jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/fitnessTracker?autoReconnect=true" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="admin" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I have tried almost all possible solutions like adding maven dependencies to the build path or cleaning the tomcat work directory .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListner</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This is misspelling, it should be

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Anyway, this class is the part of `spring-web.jar`, so you need to include it in your build. If using maven, this is something like that:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: I don't see any diference between the first two, I have downloaded and included spring.web.jar, but no change..

Comment: In the first you missed a *e* in the last term of package : ContextLoaderList**E**ner

Answer (score 5):

To resolve this error in eclipse : Right click on your project --> Propeties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add -> Java Build Path Entries -> Maven Dependencies (selecte them all) -> Finish